# PHP, gettext and LANG/LC_ALL: is interference possible?

Tags: php, gettext

I have a web server with several PHP applications on it, open to the world. There is also a test server, which is supposed to be identical, with the same applications.
Some of the applications use gettext to translate in French and Spanish; some don't.
Sometimes, a page is displayed with the wrong characters set; other times, a page is loaded with the wrong language.
I can display a page on my browser, then I refresh multiple times: sometimes the page is ok, sometimes the special characters are wrong. This is true even for applications that don't use gettext.
On the test server it normally does not happen; we think it is because the applications are affecting each other.
Is it possible that the putenv( "LANG", ... ) or the putenv( "LC_ALL", ... ) of one application can have effects on another? In fact, if at the beginning of the PHP code for the page use getenv("LANG") we get different results every time.

Comment: Sorry for not specifying, the server is Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.2 (Santiago)
PHP version 5.4.2

Comment: I asked because I've found this issue every time on Windows (something related to the threading model, where PHP processes share environment). No idea about Red Hat.